# Running a batch from an autohotkey script that deletes itself and the script

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

I'm on the verge of something but it keeps escaping me. I have an Autohotkey script that i want to run a batch that will delete the script and itself.
I made a test script that works with the batch that follows but the cmd window stays open saying that the batch can't be found

Here is the script:

```
    run, %comspec% /c start %A_Desktop%\del.bat
    ExitApp
```

and here is the batch:

```
    del %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\deltest.ahk
    del %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\del.bat
```

here is the output:

```
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop>del C:\Users\CanisMini\Desktop\deltest.ahk

C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop>del C:\Users\CanisMini\Desktop\del.bat
The batch file cannot be found.

C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop>
```

Everything deletes just fine but I need this window to close! what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with

```
del "%~f0" & exit
```